# org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

my Software version
sonarqube 7.0
maven: 3.6.3
jdk: 17
sonar-maven-plugin: 3.8.0.2131

when I run

```
mvn --batch-mode clean verify 
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar 
-Dsonar.host.url=http://*** 
-Dsonar.login=*** 
-Dsonar.password=*** 
-Dsonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true 
-Dsonar.gitlab.commit_sha=30ddd2484f6a487bcbea96775d497e0bffa87653 
-Dsonar.gitlab.ref_name=*** 
-Dsonar.gitlab.project_id=*** 
-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview  
-Dsonar.preview.excludePlugins=issueassign,scmstats 
-Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

and I've set this parameter `export SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="--illegal-access=permit"`
but it error as follows

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar (default-cli) on project train-mc: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131:sonar: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.8.0.2131
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.8.0.2131/sonar-maven-plugin-3.8.0.2131.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.16.0.226/sonar-scanner-api-2.16.0.226.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @539a50ea
```

Comment: Upgrade the plugin version to most recent one https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin furthermore upgrade Maven version as well...also the SonarQube version should be updated as well...

Answer (score 0):

May need to upgrade sonarqube server's version

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/support-java-17-in-the-sonar-maven-plugin/51931